# Reducing the size of encoded Python dict containing numpy arrays for frontend

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.6, python-3.5

I have a python dictionary that contains NumPy array of size (2, 99, 5) for its values, so the dict is looking like that:

```py
    {
        ‘key1’ :  big numpy array,
        ‘key2’ :  big numpy array,
        ‘key3’ :  big numpy array,
    }
```

I am trying to send this dict to the frontend.

First, I transform all those NumPy arrays to python list with `tolist` method, then, I used JSON to dump the dict.

The size of the JSON file is 349kb. I would like to know what is the best way to encode the dictionary to reduce the size of the resulting file that is still fast to encode.

I thought of compressing the JSON. What would be the best way to compress such a file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Json will not compress file. Its Formats the structure. The file size may increase that way.

You can use gzip.compress()

```
In [1]: from sys import getsizeof                                                                                                                     

In [2]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                            

In [3]: a = np.random.randn(100,20)                                                                                                                   

In [4]: import gzip                                                                                                                                   

In [5]: az = gzip.compress(a)                                                                                                                         

In [6]: getsizeof(a)                                                                                                                                  
Out[6]: 16112

In [7]: getsizeof(az)                                                                                                                                 
Out[7]: 15415

In [8]: import json

In [10]: aj = json.dumps(a.tolist())                                                                                                                  

In [11]: getsizeof(aj)                                                                                                                                
Out[11]: 41532
```

You can see here Json is putting overheads where gzip is compressing.

Comment: And *gzip* is very light in terms of RAM and CPU overhead.